# How to Change WooCommerce Variable product pricing by SKU or visible children id

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to  Change WooCommerce  Variable product pricing by SKU or visible children id. When I see the Variable product information by using this Code :

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable(49);
$variation_data = $product->get_children();
print_r($variation_data );
```

It returns an array  that Clearly shows variation children ids

```
 Array(
                [0] => 281
                [1] => 282
                [2] => 280
 )
```

On the Other Hand, if I see Product meta information  i see three Price. but there is no visible relation betwine Product Variation and their prices.

[image]

[image]

Guys, do you have any Suggestion How May I Change the Prices **programmatically** from my **Plugin**. Thank you.

Regards 
 javmah